# How can my Swift write to Swift instance of a C struct and then pass instance to a C function? The "write" crashes

Tags: c, swift, struct

I need to instantiate a C struct in Swift, write data to it, and finally pass it to a C function.

Builds ok, but the "write" crashes....

C struct (from .h) ...

```
struct emxArray_real_T {                // sleep stage timestamp record       ie. sleep_time_all.data
  double *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  boolean_T canFreeData;
};
```

Swift instance of above C struct...

```
var sleep_time_all = emxArray_real_T()
```

Swift init of same instance...

```
 sleep_time_all = emxArray_real_T()   // to empty prior use of array sleep_time_all.data
 sleep_time_all.allocatedSize = 0     // to reset array usage
```

Swift write to array gets ***RUN-TIME ERROR***...

```
  sleep_time_all.data[ Int( sleep_time_all.allocatedSize) * 8 ] = some_Double_number   
    //<<<<<<<<<<<< crash error: 
// "Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
```

C function

```
void compute_sleep_stats_new(const emxArray_real_T *sleep_time_all )
{...}

// Pass instantiation into C function...
compute_sleep_stats_new(   &sleep_time_all  )
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, you're not allocating any memory for `data`, so that should be expected to when you write to the NULL pointer. It's possible that you have additional code you're not showing, and I'll discuss that below.

If I'm understanding your code as you've presented it, it's like this:

```
// create a stack instance, with all 0/NULL values
var sleep_time_all = emxArray_real_T()  

// Your comment says "to empty," but this line doesn't free any memory; it just
// makes a new stack instance, and forgets (leaking if it had allocated memory)
// the previous one.
sleep_time_all = emxArray_real_T()

// Your comment says "to reset array usage," but this just sets the value to 0.
// It doesn't modify `data` in any way if you're expecting it to do that.
sleep_time_all.allocatedSize = 0

// Assuming this really is the next line as shown, since `allocatedSize` is 0, 
// this resolves to index 0, but since `data` is NULL, writing to `data[0]` is a crash
sleep_time_all.data[ Int( sleep_time_all.allocatedSize) * 8 ] = some_Double_number
```

It's possible somewhere along the way you're allocating memory for `data` and just not showing it here. If that's the case, then the mistake is likely the `* 8`, which I'm guessing might be based on "8 bytes for a Double?" If that's the case, this is double-multiplying. `data[n]` already multiplies `n` by the size of Element to get the offset. But that will still be past the end of the array, since `allocatedSize` is one greater than the last index. I think you mean:

```
// Write to the last element, assuming `allocatedSize` is the total number of Doubles
sleep_time_all.data[Int(sleep_time_all.allocatedSize) - 1] = some_Double_number
```

Comment: Hi, Rob, how do I allocate a C struct in swift?  Can't find answer anywhere.

Comment: If you're just looking for a pointer to a single heap-allocated struct, it would be `let heapAllocatedSleepTime = UnsafeMutablePointer<emxArray_real_T>.allocate(capacity: 1)`. You're then responsible for calling `deallocate()` on it at the appropriate time. If you want a heap-allocated array, it would be UnsafeMutableBufferPointer rather than a regular pointer. You can also drop the Mutable if not needed. You probably want to study this, though: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10648/